# Invisible character in default string value

Tags: protobuf-net

I am serialising a message which contains some invisible characters in a string. It works just fine but I don’t know if it’s possible to have an invisible character in the default value of the string field.

Something like that:

```
Message test1 {
    optional string testField = 1 [default = "<STX>"];
}
```

Is there any solution to do this ?

Comment: can you be very clear what you mean by "invisible character" here? I've copied/pasted that text to see if there is some unicode here - it *looks* like exactly 5 characters. So: what is the "invisible" here?

Comment: By "invisible character" I do mean the Unicode. You can replace "<STX>" by the real value : " ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a bit on whether you are using .proto schemas, or code-first. In the latter case - sure : just tell it what you want:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Test1 {
    private const string STX = "\u0002";

    [ProtoMember(1), DefaultValue(STX)]
    public string TestField1 { get; set; }

    public Test1() {
        TestField1 = STX;
    }
}
```

where `"\u0002"` is a C# literal for the STX token, the code-point with value 2.

If you are using .proto; then in all seriousness *I don't know*. The [language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) for .proto doesn't mention anything about string escaping rules. I could investigate (but not "right now"), but no particular answer is "obvious" here. If you happen to already know the answer to that for other .proto-based generators, then I'm all ears.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using .proto schemas.
I just tried this kind of .Proto with Nanopb. The Unicode character is converted to the value "\x02" in the .pb.c file.

Comment: @William so it is actually STX in the .pb.c? hmmm... I might have to tweak protogen to support these